# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' in your configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-session, spring-data-redis

i try to use spring session and i dowload this project from git 
https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/spring-session

and i get this error 
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of method sessionRedisTemplate in org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' in your configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is misleading. You are missing some dependencies.

```
compile 'redis.clients:jedis'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-pool2'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is facing an issue with springboot, might be following dependency in pom.xml is missing

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This missing dependency was misleading me to the error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue occurred due to a dependency update of Spring Boot. I solved it by opening my `application.properties` and replacing every `spring.redis` with `spring.data.redis`.